# Schedule job to perform actions for a configurable time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I've to perform some actions after a configurable threshold is reached. Let me explain the scenario:

Let's say I've following configuration in the database:

```
Time      Action 
---------------
5 min      A1
10 min     A2
20 min     A3
```

I now have to schedule a job (may be in sidekiq) such that:

```
At 5th min - action A1 is triggered
At 10th min - action A2 is triggered
At 20th min - action A3 is triggered
Reset the timer
At 25th min - action A1 is triggered
so on..
```

I know I should've described the effort that I've done but I'm clueless right now and need a direction to achieve this.

Comment: If you are open to a gem solution, ``sidekiq-scheduler`` allows you to define jobs that fire on intervals, including setting a delay on the first execution (e.g., A1 would be ``every: ['20m', first_in: '5m']``, etc.). You can also manually trigger reloading schedules when config changes. See https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler#schedule-types for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Without some form of `JobQueue` gem.

```
objects = IterableTimeObject.all

while(some_condition)
   objects.each do |obj|
       sleep(obj.time*60)
       Call_Some_Task
   end
end
```

Using [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

```
objects = IterableTimeObject.all
max_minute = objects.map{|obj| obj.time}.max

while(some_condition)
   objects.each do |obj|
      PerformSomeJob.set(wait: 
          obj.time*60.seconds).perform_later(params1, params2)
   end
   sleep(max_minute*60)
end
```

Notice the time is the number of minute on the object. `obj.time*60` actually gives the number of seconds to wait before performing the Job.
Relax the process for the maximum minutes and resume again.
Hope this helps.